# Connect server to internet over local machine

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, scp

Ive got access to a server over ssh to run some experiments and need to download some packages over the internet to perform these. Unfortunately, the server has no connection to the internet, or blocks the outgoing connection, I'm not sure. But as mentioned before, I can connect to the machine over ssh or transfer files via scp from my local machine.

Is there a way I can relay the internet connection of the server over my local machine so that I can download the required packages? Ive looked into ssh tunneling but due to my inexperience I was unsuccessful.

Edit: Server system is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, my local machine is mac os x, but I have a Ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: More details are required here. What OSes are we talking? Presumably at least one of them is linux, seeing as you're talking about ssh/scp. Also, how is your routing tables set up?

Comment: Of course. I added details to the question. I don't know how the routing tables are set up. Is there a way I can find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. I used to be in a similar situation, and I used an ssh connection from the server to the client to set-up a SOCKS proxy. You can set it up straightforwardly with the aid of the flag *-D  port number* (for instance 10001) when making an SSH connection from the server to the client.

(on the server, make a SSH connection to the client and leave this open:)

> ssh -D 10001 *client*

Subsequently, you can use [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) in another terminal to allow programs to make TCP connection to the outside world through the newly created SOCKS proxy. The configuration of proxychains is very straightforward, just add one row to your proxychains.conf file:

```
socks5 127.0.0.1 10001
```

to notify the proxychains how the proxyserver can be reached.
After that, you can use proxychains in the following way, for example to tell wget to use the proxy:

> proxychains wget *address*

As soon as you close the first connection, the proxy ceases to exist.

You didn't mention whether you are able to connect from the server directly to the client (maybe due to firewall settings you can't?). If that is the case, you could still use this method, although you could make a reverse tunnel first:

(on the client, make an SSH connection to the server and make a reverse tunnel:)

> ssh -R 9999:localhost:22 *server*

This makes a connection to the server, and creates a port (in this example 9999) that connects back to the client on port 22 (defaults SSH port). On the server, you can then make a connection to the client connecting through this tunnel:

> ssh -p 9999 -D 10001 ***localhost***

If you don't want to set-up a SOCKS proxy altogether, then you are probably better off making an SSH connection from the server to the client, and make a local tunnel (with -L) to the destination if you only want to reach a specific server.

Comment: I'm using proxychains-ng for this, proxychains didn't seem to function properly. You may have a mistake in your code: ssh -R 9999:localhost:22 server opens port 9999 on the server and connects to port 22 on my machine. So shouldn't the subsequent command be ssh -p 22 -D 10001 client, that is -p should have the value 22 and not 9999? I've tried both variants and unfortunately, neither can establish a connection to the client.

Comment: I'm not sure whether 'proxy_dns' in the configuration file for proxychains is uncommented by default, but you want to use this too as your machine probably has no access to a DNS server either. By doing so, you allow the domain name translations to be done by the proxy too.

Comment: You are right, the last one should not say client but localhost. Sorry, will fix that in the post. Once you've opened the reverse tunnel, it indeed opens port 9999 on the server and connects to port 22 on the client, as you want. You should leave this terminal as is, because it keeps that tunnel alive. In another terminal on the server, you should then be able to ssh -p 9999 -D 10001 *localhost* to go through the tunnel to your client, and get the proxy alive. Then, you should then be able to use the proxy with proxychains-ng just fine, I've just tested it once more.

Comment: In case you only want to download files from known locations, it turns out you don't need proxychains and use [wget directly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38761), which knows how to access SOCKS proxies

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was capable of connecting the server to my client thanks to your fix! Concerning proxchains, am I suppose to run this on the client or on the server? Because running it on the server does not seem to function. E.g /proxychains4 -f src/proxychains.conf ping www.google.de (the long command is taken from the github readme of proxychain-ng)

Comment: In the proxchains.config files the following is written on the last few lines:
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 10001

The rest is taken as is from the github (https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/blob/master/src/proxychains.conf). The file proxy_dns is also uncommented by default.

Comment: Funnily enough, this works on the server: ./proxychains4 -f src/proxychains.conf telnet google.com 80
Am I misunderstanding how proxychains works?

Comment: You should run proxychains on the server indeed, because you wanted to have access to the internet on the server. So if you managed to connect to a external webserver using telnet via proxychains. That's good. You should also be able to use other programs such as _apt-get_ or _wget_ with proxychains. Does that work for you now?